# Odd Go Behavior - Generics Struct Returns

Tags: go, generics

Trying to recreate Java Optionals in Go (for learning purposes). Interestingly, returning a value directly vs returning a value through a variable assignment have different behaviours, one is working other is not.
In Of method when I return `EmptyOptional` I am getting compile time error, but when I return `&optional[TT]{}` its working.

```golang
package utils

type TT interface{}
type Optional[T TT] interface {
    Of(t T) Optional[T]
    Map(func() Optional[T]) Optional[T]
}

var EmptyOptional = &optional[TT]{}

type optional[T any] struct {
    t T
}

func (o *optional[TT]) Of(t TT) Optional[TT] {
    if t == nil {
//      return &optional[TT]{} // <<-- Working 
        return EmptyOptional   // <<-- Not Working 
    }
    return nil
}
func (o *optional[TT]) Map(func() Optional[TT]) Optional[TT] {
    return nil

}
```

Compile Time Error

```
./prog.go:24:10: cannot use EmptyOptional (variable of type *optional[TT]) as Optional[TT] value in return statement: *optional[TT] does not implement Optional[TT] (wrong type for method Map)
        have Map(func() main.Optional[main.TT]) main.Optional[main.TT]
        want Map(func() main.Optional[TT]) main.Optional[TT]
```

First week of go today. Tried my best to understand what this behaviour is called.

Comment: "First week of go today" Stop using "generics", especially as they just share the name with Java's generics. Java's Optional is a bad idea in Go (no matter how much you fancy Java's Optional). To your problem (a 100% duplicate): There is no covariance in Go's type system. Optional[T] and Optional[TT] have nothing in common as types.

Comment: This would be easier to read with actual names vs. placeholders, but those aren't compatible types.

Comment: Didn't I mention its for learning purpose? @Volker?

Comment: If anything I get the feeling you are so far ahead in learning curve.. that you have forgotten people learn by trying. @Volker

Comment: @amangoyal: If you're new to learning Go, starting with generics is going to be rough as we're all still figuring out how they best fit into the language. Much of this discovery is based on modifying existing programs that solve real problem, and seeing how they fit. Doing this from a theoretical perspective won't help you. I would recommend solving some practical problems in Go without generics, specifically things around concurrency and implicit interfaces. Go generics feel better when they're the last resort, as other patterns can often get you there in a simpler way.

Comment: @amangoyal: knowing how to ride a bike is a valid skill.  Learning how to drive a car is a valid goal.  Literally nobody ever learned how to drive a car by ripping out the driver's seat, steering wheel and engine and putting in a saddle, handlebars and a chain drive with a pedal crank. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more problems than you acknowledge.  Placing your code in a playground, the code which you claim is "working" cannot be reached by the compiler as it is contained within an illegal `if` statement:

```
invalid operation: t == nil (mismatched types TT and untyped nil)
```

Creating an MVCE in a go playground can help eliminate such problems and present a scenario that people may engage with and work on to help with your problem (and doing so might help you realise the problem yourself).

Here is [a playground containing your initial code that illustrates that problem](https://go.dev/play/p/ZeKpwZArUPr).

That problem aside, and ignoring that trying to re-create Java optionals in Go is of little value in terms of a learning exercise...

### The Problem

`EmptyOptional` is a value of the instantiated `optional[T]` type with `T` of type `TT` (a redundant redeclaration of a type exactly equivalent to the existing `any` type).

The `Of` method is a method of a generic type `Optional[T]`.  The only scenario in which `Of` might conceivable return an `EmptyOptional` is the specific case where the type parameter for `Optional[T]` is the same type as the instance type of `EmptyOptional`: i.e. `TT`.

But this is impossible since the `Of[T]` method is declared as *returning a value of generic type*; attempting to return *a value of some **concrete** type is guaranteed to be impossible*.  It reduces the generic `Optional[T]` type to a dependency on an `any` type argument.  i.e. to use `EmptyOptional`, `Optional[T]` cannot be generic but must be a non-generic type operating with fields, method arguments and return values of type `any`.

### Simplify to Clarify

Your choice of symbols is not helping you understand the problem you have created.  This alternative may help:

```golang
package utils

type Optional[T any] interface {
    Of(t T) Optional[T]
}

var EmptyOptional = &optional[any]{}

type optional[T any] struct {
    t T
}

func (o *optional[T]) Of(t T) Optional[T] {
    //return &optional[T]{} // <<-- 'Working'
    return EmptyOptional // <<-- ERROR: EmptyOptional is of a type already instantiated as Optional[any]
}
```

This is also [available in a playground for further exploration](https://go.dev/play/p/S0gDWfcaCzL) should you wish.

In this simplified version I have removed the illegal and differently problematic `if` statement.  I have also removed the redundant `TT` interface and the unnecessary `Map` method as these are entirely unrelated to the problem.

From this simplified example it should be far more obvious that `EmptyOptional`, which is *a concrete instantiation of a generic type with a specific type argument* (`any`) cannot be used where a `Optional[T]` (i.e. not yet instantiated) generic.

Consider this hypothetical:

```golang
type OptionalInt optional[int]
```

This instantiates a type with an `Of[int]` method returning an `Optional[int]` but `EmptyOptional` is of type `Optional[any]`.

See the problem?

### Supplementary

Instantiated generic types are not compatible even if instantiated with the same type argument; they are always distinct types, as [illustrated in this final playground](https://go.dev/play/p/VZuerq9QHCc):

```golang
type generic[T any] struct{ v T }

type genericInt generic[int]
type otherGenericInt generic[int]

func main() {
    a := genericInt{42}
    aa := genericInt{42}
    fmt.Println(a == aa) // this is OK: a and aa are of the same type, supporting comparable: evaluates as 'true'

    // neither of these declarations of b yields a value that is comparable with a,
    // being of different types to a in both cases

    b := generic[int]{42}
    //  b := otherGenericInt{42}
    fmt.Println(a.v == b.v) // this is fine, but...
    fmt.Println(a == b)     // ERROR: mismatched types
}
```

In short: GoLang is not Java; it also is not JavaScript. :)

### What To Do Instead?

The idiomatic way to implement optionality (the behaviour, not the type) in GoLang is to simply use a pointer, with `nil` identifying the `not present` property.  Generics are not involved in this.

Get used to this and you will find it much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider two things when working with generics in go.

Type **definitions** and type **instantiations**.

#### [definition](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions)

The definition is yet to be defined which concrete type it will assume once it is used. (string, user defined type, etc)

#### [instantiation](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Instantiations)

The instantiation is the telling of which underlying type it is now.

#### explanation

The problem is `EmptyOptional` already **instantiate** its type as TT and could not assume an `Optional[string]` for example If needed in a case where `(o *optional[string])Of(t string) Optional[string]` returning `&optional[TT]` would not be the same as the promised `Optional[string]` value.

```
./prog.go:22:10: cannot use EmptyOptional (variable of type *optional[TT]) as Optional[TT] value in return statement: *optional[TT] does not implement Optional[TT] (wrong type for method Map)
        have Map(func() main.Optional[main.TT]) main.Optional[main.TT]
        want Map(func() main.Optional[TT]) main.Optional[TT]
```

We can see in the compile error we are returning an main.Optional[main.TT] main.TT being an instantiation and we want an TT as definition because it must be able to assume other types that the generic interface supports.

Here is a snippet in go playgrounds to better illustrate this scenario for different types.

https://goplay.tools/snippet/xOTCSn7Tq6y

*EDIT: also there is a fix for the `t == nil` using reflect*